# Throw error when setting an attribute

Tags: python

I have a class with a property `deleted`. The user must use the `ob.delete()` method. If he attempts to directly do `ob.deleted = True`, he should get an error.

```
class A(ORMBaseClass):
    deleted = False

    def delete(self):
        self.deleted = True


a = A()
a.delete() # works
print(a.delete) # works
a.deleted = True # must throw exception
Exception: you cannot directly set deleted
```

I tried it with overloading `__setattr__` but that affects `ob.delete()` as well.

Properties with a `ob._deleted` private attribute and `ob.deleted` property are not suitable as the class is an ORM model and he faces the UX inconsistency of `session.query(A).filter(A._deleted == True)` and `a.deleted=True`.

I know Python has no perfectly safe way of doing this, I just want to stop and inform the user who causally sets it.

Comment: what python do you use? I can't confirm the problem with python-3.6 on Arch Linux/x86-64

Comment: same here with 2.7/ OsX

Comment: @user3159253 and Ashish, I've written badly, there is no existing error. I fixed the confusing wording.

Comment: You should use a property. But keep in mind that Python is very dynam and open, so there is no way to ultimately protect attribute.

Comment: @KlausD. I addressed property in question.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._deleted = False

    @property
    def deleted(self):
        return self._deleted

    @deleted.setter
    def deleted(self, value):
        raise Exception("Can't directly set deleted")

    def delete(self):
        self._deleted = True
```

You specify properties' get and set methods, and raise exception if setter is called directly. This will work on `Python` 2.7 and 3.x.

Answer (score 2):

You *could* do this:

```
def __setattr__(self, name, value):
    if name == 'deleted':
        raise AttributeError("you cannot directly set deleted")
    object.__setattr__(self, name, value)
```

Then, in `delete`, you have to go around it by directly calling `object.__setattr__(self, 'deleted', True)`.

But you probably shouldn't really do any of that. If you want a member variable to be "private", just make its name start with an underscore, e.g. `_deleted`. It will still be writable, but it is a convention which means "the variable is private, don't touch it".

Comment: Use two underscore for a private. Two underscore is more than a convention, it will force python to use name mangling. Inside the class the attribute will be `__deleted` but outside the class `__deleted` will not exist. It will be referred as `_CLASS__attribute`. It's especially good when you want inherited class to not mess if your attributes.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix Actually, I would not recommend using two underscores for private variables as a general rule. Neither `_` nor `__` makes a veriable truly private. Both leave it absolutely accesible. The latter just requires more typing. Double underscore is useful in some situations involving inheritance. For simple "privacy", in Python you have to rely on conventions anyway, so the simpler solution with a single underscore is something I would prefer almost every time.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a better solution in my regard which is a mix of previous solutions.

You can make use of python mechanics for private members (name mangling)

```
class A(ORMBaseClass):
    __deleted = False

    def delete(self):
        self.__deleted = True

    @property
    def deleted(self):
        return self.__deleted
```

First notice, the member is using two underscore to make the variable private. Using two underscore is more than a convention like the proposed 1 underscore. It will make python use name mangling on the attribute. In this case the only way to access this attribute is through `obj._A__deleted` It's still writable but it's much better than using one underscore.

Now you have a simple method that set `__deleted` to `True` and a property that returns the value. Nothing complicated here.

Why name mangling is important?

Here if you where to do this:

```
class B(A):
    __deleted = True

    @property
    def deleted2(self):
        return self.__deleted
```

Guess what would be the return value of:

```
obj = B()
obj.deleted
```

If you guessed `False` then you're right! The class `B` will define an attribute named `_B__deleted` while the class A `_A__deleted`. As you can see name mangling prevent sub class to access accidentally attributes from the upper class. And when you try to access `__deleted` from anywhere outside the classes the attribute will be undefined...

In theory, if you wanted to have real private you could use a meta class that will construct something like that with random names every time a class is constructed.